# F# If statement expecting unit from float

Tags: if-statement, f#

the statement is fine until the final elif which it then has the error "Was expected to have type unit"

```
type BankAcc = {AccNum:int; mutable  Balance:float} with

    member this.Withdraw(amount,?withdrawal) =
     let withdrawAmount = this.Balance * float amount
     match withdrawal with
      | None -> withdrawAmount
      | Some deduct -> withdrawAmount - deduct
let Account ={AccNum=123;Balance = 15.00}

Account.Withdraw(25.00) // withdrawing 25 from an account with a balance of 15

let test Balance withdrawAmount =
  if Balance = withdrawAmount then "Equals"
  elif Balance < withdrawAmount then "Balance too low"
  else Balance - withdrawAmount 

  Account={AccNum =0001; Balance=0.00};   

let CheckAccount Balance = 
    if Balance < 10.00 then "Balance is low"
    elif Balance >= 10.00 && Balance <= 100.00 then "Balance is ok"
    elif Balance > 100.00 then "balance is high"

let sort = Seq.unfold(fun Balance -> if(snd Balance => 50)then List.map(fun accounts-> Balance <50) list1)
```

Comment: The final `elif` should just be an `else`; currently you have an `if` without an `else` there, which isn't allowed, unless the `if` branch returns `unit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So let's abstract your code a little bit:

```
if a then b
elif x then y
elif p then q
```

From this, the compiler can tell that when `a = true`, the result should be `b`. When `a = false`, it should check `x` next, and if `x = true`, the result should be `y`. Now, if both `a` and `x` turn out to be `false`, the compiler knows to proceed to checking `p`, and if `p = true`, then the result is `q`.

But here's the question: what should the result be when all three, `a`, `b`, and `p` turn out to be false?

You haven't told the compiler what to do in that case, so of course it complains!

---

But why does it complain so cryptically? What does `unit` have to do with it?

This has to do with a small syntactic relaxation that exists in F# to ease the developers' life. You see, because F# is not a *pure* functional language, which means that it can have arbitrary side-effects, very often those side-effects don't return any meaningful value, like `printf` for example:

```
> printf "foo"
it : unit = ()
```

The function doesn't have anything good to return, but there has to be some return type, and there is a special type just for this occasion - `unit`. It's a special type that has exactly one value, so it doesn't mean anything.

Now let's see what happens if I need to put my `printf` call inside an `if`: in any `if`, both `then` and `else` branches must have the same type, otherwise it's not clear what the type of the whole `if` expression should be. Therefore, if my `then` branch contains a `printf`, my else branch must also be of type `unit`. So I am forced to always put this meaningless appendix there:

```
> if foo then printf "bar" else ()
it : unit = ()
```

This is annoying. In fact, so annoying it is that the F# language has a special case for it: when my `then` branch is of type `unit`, I can omit the `else` branch altogether, and the compiler will just assume that I meant to say `else ()`:

```
> if foo then printf "bar"
it : unit = ()
```

So this is what happens in your case: since you have omitted the `else` branch, the compiler assumes that all `then` branches must be of type `unit`, but they are clearly of type `float`, so the compiler complains.

---

To fix this, you need to provide an `else` branch. Judging by your code, it seems to me that you really had in mind there possible cases: (1) less than 10, (2) between 10 and 100, and (3) everything else. If so, the "everything else" branch should be the `else`:

```
if Balance < 10.00 then "Balance is low" 
elif Balance >= 10.00 && Balance <= 100.00 then "Balance is ok" 
else "balance is high"
```

---

P.S. after you fix this, you'll have a similar problem in the `test` function: the two `then` branches are `string`, but the `else` branch is `float`